# Bluetooth microphone quality worse on Ubuntu than on iPhone

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a pair of Sennheiser HD 4.50 bluetooth headphones that I want to use for phone conferences.  When I connect them to my iPhone and dial in from there, people tell me microphone quality is excellent.  When I connect them to my Ubuntu computer and dial in, they tell me microphone quality is terrible.

I confirmed this by recording a call on a third device, see WAV file [here](http://mat.exon.name/headphones.wav) (link may go away at some point).  Subjectively, it's not "used the wrong codec" terrible, it just sounds a bit fuzzy and compressed.  It's more like what you hear when you playback in HSP mode instead of A2DP mode, and in fact if you playback in HSP mode it's hard to tell the difference.  But with phone conferences you can't afford substandard audio, and this quality is bad enough to make Ubuntu unusable.

Is there some way to fix this?  Are there different codecs or bandwidths that are being negotiated behind the scenes that I should know about?  Or do iPhones have some kind of clever post-processing that happens in the audio stack that produces better results?

Answer (score 0):

An old Question, may be asked before but, it's all about the codex.

Long story short, the best work ahead I do is:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634106/420338

A screnshoot with the default settings.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyZJ2.png)

A screenshot with the updated settings[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMcME.png)

Steps to consider:
Codecs are found up in here, AAC works best for my case.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jif4.png)

Comment: What about later when the screen shots are gone and can not be seen?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).